# How can I make the variable dynamically

Tags: apex-email-service, variable

I add an email handler service to my org. How can I change the syntax that the c. variable is also dynamically? I tried to add a string like String api_name = 'c.' + fi + '__c' but it does'nt work. Any ideas?

```
    bt__c C = new bt__c();        
    if(email.plainTextBody != Null && email.plainTextBody != '') {
        String[] emailBodyRows = email.plainTextBody.split('\n');
        Set<String> fieldimport = new Set<String>{'firstname', 'phone'};
             FOR (Integer i = 0; i < emailBodyRows.size(); i++) {
                 FOR (String fi : fieldimport) {                  
                     IF (emailBodyRows[i].contains(fi)) {
                    // the next row shoulb be dynamically 
                        **c.vorname__c = emailBodyRows[i].substringAfter(fi);**
                    }
                 }
             }
      }
      insert c;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All types such as `bt__c` support the SObject methods described here [SObject Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm) presumably by extending `SObject`. And there are various "describe" method to convert string names into tokens that have various methods avaiable.

So in your code:

```
// Vary these as needed
String objectName = 'bt__c';
String fieldName = 'vorname__c';

SObjectType t = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(objectName);
SObject c = t.newSObject();
...
    c.put(fieldName, emailBodyRows[i].substringAfter(fi));
...
insert c;
```

Comment: it works. Can I remove the row from the email.plainTextBody which was found? because at the end I add the whole mail to a note and I just want to include info which I can't stored in fields.

Comment: @peXeq Yes you can e.g. loop in reverse order and use the list remove by index method. Best to not keep commenting for other answers here; the format is 1Q and 1A.